# Is SQL Server 2012 express serverless

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

Hi I have installed **Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop**. I am not sure if the sql server software that that came with Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop is serverless or not. I have installed this at work and don't want a server installed on my computer because I am sure it opens ports which will be a security issue at work. Do you know if it is serverless?

Comment: Why would "serverless" affect which ports are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is definitely a server involved.

You don't need to worry about ports being opened though. Assuming you have a Firewall blocking the ports, the installation of SQL Server Express won't modify that without your permission.